# python-nested-dictionary - keys

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

i am iterating a **nested** dictionary using dict.keys() method. code works well if the dictionary is nested however if the dictionary is not nested , it throws an error (i.e)

```
{"a":{1:'i'}}
```

for above dictionary the code works fine but following dictionary it fails

```
{"a":1}
```

In my iteration , I wish to not throw error if the dictionary is not having further keys. per requirement we may pass nested or non-nested dictionaries.

Following is the sample code:

```
global n
n=0
df = pd.DataFrame(index = np.arange(10), columns = ['column0'])
def iterate_dict(dict):
    global n
    for j in dict.keys()
        df[n] = j
        n = n+1
    return dict
#function call
iterate_dict({"a":1})
```

*Error Message:*

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'`

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You must have tried calling `iterate_dict({"a":1})` with string argument like `iterate_dict("{a:1}")` which gives error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'`.
Try using:

```
returned_dict = iterate_dict({"a": 1})
```

It should work.

Adding working code here:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

global n
n = 0
df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(10), columns=['column0'])


def iterate_dict(dict):
    global n
    for j in dict.keys():
        df[n] = j
        n = n + 1
    return dict


# function call
iterate_dict({"a": 1})
print(df.head())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
  column0  0
0     NaN  a
1     NaN  a
2     NaN  a
3     NaN  a
4     NaN  a
```

Comment: I have added working code in the answer, can you try that, it works without any error.